# передать несколько параметров одной переменной через get-запрос

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, requests

Всем привет!
вопрос: есть код, который делает 3 похожих get-запроса, например:

```
r1 = requests.get('http://mysite.com/check.php?' + 'userid=666&userage=18')
r2 = requests.get('http://mysite.com/check.php?' + 'userid=777&userage=22')
r3 = requests.get('http://mysite.com/check.php?' + 'userid=888&userage=26')
```

можно ли посредством Python объединить все три запроса в один (один запрос вместо трех- это цель)? пробовал разные конструкции, но что то не едет.

Comment: Можно ли сделать один запрос вместо трёх - спрашивайте у администратора сервера. Если он не сделал обработку нескольких юзеров в своём check.php, то очевидно никак. Если администратор это вы и вы писали check.php - вам же виднее, можно или нельзя сделать :)

Comment: Можно же массив передать `userage[666]=18&userage[777]=22`

Comment: @vp_arth только если check.php умеен обрабатывать такое

Comment: Не хочет заставим, не может научим)

Comment: нет сервер воспринимает только первые параметры, видимо действительно так настроен :( есть варианты ускорить отправку 3х запросов? а то они всю работу тормозят. Многопоток через threading как я понимаю будет неэффективен ввиду ожидания потоком ответа сервера и GIL

Comment: @babyborn  вы понимаете неправильно. Если у вас вопрос как ускорить отправку трёх запросов, то задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Можно так:

```
for idx, userid, userage in zip((1, 2, 3),
                                (666, 777, 888),
                                (18, 22, 26)):
    locals()['r{}'.format(idx)] = requests.get('http://mysite.com/check.php?userid={}&userage={}'.format(userid, userage))
```

Comment: Это всё ещё три запроса, а автор хочет один запрос